# MediaWiki Stylesheet Not Loading (load.php shows main page)

Tags: php, docker, apache, mediawiki, mediawiki-installation

After installing mediawiki, stylesheets don't load properly. Here are minimum reproduction instructions:

Using the following git repo: https://sourceforge.net/p/mediawiki-problem/code/ci/step1/tree/ starting with branch `step1`,

1. `./startup` starts the wiki, database, and reverse proxy
2. `docker container exec -ti swarm_lithia-wiki<tab> bash` to run bash in the mediawiki container
3. Inside the container, `mkdir lithia && mv * lithia;` moves everything to the `lithia` directory so that everything can be served properly
4. Visit http://localhost:80/lithia in a web browser, and I see the prompt to install

During the install, I set the following settings:

- Database host `lithia-db` (matching the service name in the docker compose file)
- Database name `lithia`
- Database table prefix `li_`
- Database username `root`
- Database password `moresecurepassword`
- Next
- Uncheck "Use the same account as for installation"
- Database username `lithiauser`
- Database password `somesecurepassword`
- Check "Create the account..."
- Continue
- Name of wiki `Lithia`
- Your username: `lmat`
- Password: `goodpassword`
- Select "I'm bored..." then Continue then Continue

Everything looks good.

Save `LocalSettings.php` in the git repository in `/lithia-wiki`.

- Check out `step2` in the repo to add the `LocalSettings.php` volume to `swarm.yml`.
- Run `./startup` again to restart the service which will undo the `mv` above as well as mount the `LocalSettings.php` file.

### Now behold, the page loads without CSS

Investigating the problem, I see the following in the browser console:

```
Refused to apply style from
'http://localhost/lithia/load.php?lang=en&modules=skins.vector.styles.legacy&only=styles&skin=vector'
because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict
MIME checking is enabled.
```

Visiting that page, http://localhost/lithia/load.php?lang=en&modules=skins.vector.styles.legacy&only=styles&skin=vector, it is loading the main page.

How should I fix this? What did I do wrong during setup?

Comment: It looks like this question has a downvote and two close requests without any comments? What's wrong? Does the problem take too long to reproduce? Is it too specific to my usecase? Hosting mediawiki 1) using docker 2) behind a proxy 3) at a non-root location seems common enough to me, but maybe I'm blind due to my own usecase.

Answer (score 2):

> `because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type`

That usually happens when [MediaWiki](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki) cannot find the specified resources, often due to misconfigurations or path issues.

You need to debug `load.php`, as suggested in [`Manual:load.php`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Load.php) and [this thread](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Topic:Rljqwtpz7uxoec6c)

Inside your MediaWiki container, navigate to the `maintenance` folder and execute `eval.php` to check if your MediaWiki environment is functioning correctly.

```bash
cd /path/to/mediawiki/maintenance
php eval.php
```

Enter some simple MediaWiki PHP commands to see if they execute successfully.

See "[The wiki appears without styles applied and images are missing](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Common_errors_and_symptoms#The_wiki_appears_without_styles_applied_and_images_are_missing)":
MediaWiki's [`ResourceLoader`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/ResourceLoader) is responsible for delivering CSS and JS. Make sure that the URLs are correctly configured. Check `LocalSettings.php` to make sure [`$wgScriptPath`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Special:MyLanguage/Manual:$wgScriptPath), [`$wgResourceBasePath`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgResourceBasePath) and other URL settings are correctly set.

And make sure that URL rewriting is configured correctly in your web server. That can cause unexpected behavior if incorrectly set up. Validate that the web server is properly forwarding requests to MediaWiki.

Since Docker, inspect your Dockerfile and docker-compose file for any issues that may cause this problem. File permission issue due to a host directory mount could be a problem.

Comment: Thank you. This looks like a comprehensive list of debugging steps to try to nail down the problem!

Comment: @lmat-ReinstateMonica It does, let me know what you find out from that list.